# How to create a tableview in Tizen Native App

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm new to Tizen and im trying to create a tableview with tizen native app. I found we need FUi.h, FApp.h files which is not available in my Tizen IDE (2.3.0). Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EFL to create Tableview in Tizen. There are api's for table and box creation in EFL for tizen native app's UI. just go to this link to find some guideline.

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__Table.html